# Handlebars - split string and iterate within {{each}}

Tags: javascript, html, json, handlebars.js

Basically I am rendering a JSON file into a HTML template with Handlebars and all works fine except for one value where I get returned a string with comma separated values.

JSON file:

```
[
{
        "venue_state": "Everywhere",
        "venue_country": "United States",
        "venue_lat": "34.2347",
        "venue_lng": "-77.9482",
        "rating_score": "4",
        "created_at": "2022-07-01 17:13:16",
        "flavor_profiles": "malty,biscuity,grainy,clove,banana"
},
{
....
}
]
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

 <!--handlebars template-->
    <script id="checkin-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}
    <div class="container">
       <h1>{{venue_country}}<h2>
       <p>{{venue_state}}</p>
        <div class="some-other-container">
            <h1>{{rating_score}}</h1>
        </div>
         <ul class="tags">
                <li><a href="#" class="tag">{{flavor_profiles}}</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
    </script>
<div class="output"></div>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "testdata.json", false);
    request.send(null);
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    //console.log(data);
    
    //compile template and fill with data
    var source = $("#checkin-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    $('.output').append(template(data));

});
```

This works except for `{{flavor_profiles}}`. What I **want** to get rendered is this

```
         <ul class="tags">
                <li><a href="#" class="tag">malty</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="tag">biscuity</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="tag">grainy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="tag">clove</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="tag">banana</a></li>
         </ul>
```

What I **actually get** is

```
         <ul class="tags">
                <li><a href="#" class="tag">malty,biscuity,grainy,clove,banana</a></li>
         </ul>
```

and I guess it is because I get returned a string of comma separated values instead of an array?

I tried something like this

```
    <script id="checkin-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}
    <div class="container">
       <h1>{{venue_country}}<h2>
       <p>{{venue_state}}</p>
        <div class="some-other-container">
            <h1>{{rating_score}}</h1>
        </div>
         <ul class="tags">
            {{#each flavor_profiles}}
                <li><a href="#" class="tag">{{this}}</a></li>
            {{/each}}
         </ul>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
    </script>
```

and I also tried to register some helper function in `script.js` which did not work. This is a small hobby thing where I am just visualizing something in another way. So I don't want to use further frameworks or server side processing. The JSON gets pulled from elsewhere so I can't change how it looks. Is there any way within Handlebars to render my desired output?

Comment: To get the result you want you will need to `#each` over `flavor_profiles`, but, for that to work, the value of `flavor_profiles` must be an array in your JSON file, not a string as it is in your example. If you can't change the JSON file, then you will need to create a helper to split the `flavor_profiles` value into an array so it can be looped over with `#each`.

Comment: Thanks, since I'm parsing the file with `var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);` can I maybe use the `reviver` parameter from JSON.parse? Read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) but not sure how to go about it.

Comment: If you are the owner of your JSON file, you can just change it to: ` "flavor_profiles": ["malty", "biscuity", "grainy", "clove" , "banana"]`

Comment: Yes, sure but it's just an example, the actual file has a few thousand entries like this. Sometimes `flavor_profiles` contains a single word, sometimes multiple words, sometimes it is empty.

Comment: If it is intended as an array then I would make it one. Single word: `["one"]`; multiple words: `["one", "two"]`; empty: `[]`. The `reviver` might be a way to do this, I have never used it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this

script.js

```
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText, function(key, x) {
        if (key === "flavor_profiles") {
           x = x.split(',');
        return x;
        }
        return x;
     });
```

HTML

```
<ul class="tags">
     {{#each flavor_profiles}}
     <li><a href="#" class="tag">{{this}}</a></li>
     {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think little bit of j Query can help with your problem. I don't know this is what you expected.

HTML

```
<script id="checkin-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}
    <div class="container">
    <h1>{{venue_country}}<h2>
    <p>{{venue_state}}</p>
        <div class="some-other-container">
            <h1>{{rating_score}}</h1>
        </div>
        <ul class="tags" id="stringToList">
            {{flavor_profiles}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
<div class="output"></div>
```

and new function to script.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("[id='stringToList']").each(function () {
        let el = $(this).text().toString().split(",").map(item => `<li><a href="#" class="tag">${item}</a></li>`).join('')
        $(this).html(el)
    })
});
```